# How to login to this poorly formatted HTML form using powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, html

I have an issue trying to login to the following HTML form using powershell: *html updated to show log in button*

```
<tr>
<tr><td  align='right'  valign=top   bgcolor='#ffffff'  width=15%><font face='Arial,  Helvetica, Verdana' size=-1 color=#000000 id=copy>User name or Email:</font></td><td  valign=bottom><input type='text' name=AutoLogin size=30><tr><td  align='right'  valign=top   bgcolor='#ffffff'  width=15%><font face='Arial, Helvetica, Verdana' size=-1 color=#000000 id=copy>Password:</font></td><td valign=bottom><input type='password'  name=AutoPassword size=30>

</tr></table>
<br>
<table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 border=0 bordercolor=#ffffff width=100% height=*>

<tr>
<tr><td><input type=submit value="Log In">
```

The powershell code to login to the page:

```
& "$env:programfiles\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" 'https://login-url.asp'

$win = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
$try = 0
$ie2 = $null
do {
Start-Sleep -milliseconds 500
$ie2 = @($win.windows() | ? { $_.locationName -like '*Log In*' })[0]
$try ++
if ($try -gt 20) {
Throw "Web Page cannot be opened."
}
} while ($ie2 -eq $null)

$ie2.document
$ie2.Document.body.innerHTML

$doc = $ie2.document

$username = 'xxxxx'
$password = 'xxxxx'

#username field
$usernameField = $doc.getElementsByName("desc")
Write-Host "Username field is?"
$usernameField

#password field
$passwordField = $doc.getElementsByName("password")
Write-Host "Password field is?"
$passwordField

$submitButton = $doc.getElementById('submit')
$submitButton.click()

do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie2.Busy))
```

Comment: Hmmm, IMHO you only need the elements (`getElementsByName`) with the name `desc` and `password`

Comment: that throws the following error:
`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At E:\getNotes.ps1:14 char:48
+         $usernameField = $doc.getElementsByName <<<< ("desc")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementsByName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`
I then get the following output:
`Username field is?:
className                        : 

onhelp                           : 
onclick                          : 
ondblclick                       : ` - and the list continues...

Comment: What is `$doc`? Do you create it with `new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application` and `....Navigate2("http://yoururl")`? Can you please show a little bit more code?

Comment: `$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application
# Navigate to login page
$ie.navigate("https://url-to-login/~account/login/customer.asp")
do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))

$doc = $ie.document

$username = 'xxxxx'
$password = 'xxxxx'

try {

        $usernameField = $doc.getElementsByName("desc")`

Comment: Well, looks good so far. Maybe [this](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/04/03/accessing-internet-explorer.aspx) is your problem?

Comment: thanks for this, still having a go with it - will let you know if i get anywhere - this actually causes IE to popup on the screen, what I need the script to do later on is navigate through a list of webpages and parse them, so i kind of need it to be done in the background (if that makes sense) is that possible?

Comment: ok, it's not throwing any errors now but I'm still baffled by the output? it's outputting a big list of objects?:
`Script                            : mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class
all                               : System.__ComObject
body                              : mshtml.HTMLBodyClass
activeElement                     : mshtml.HTMLBodyClass
images                            : System.__ComObject
applets                           : System.__ComObject
links                             : System.__ComObject
forms                             : System.__ComObject` ... and list continues?

Comment: from the list it's printing out I can see:
`outerHTML                               : <INPUT value="" size=30 type=password name=password>`
???

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add the new code your are using? Because it's getting hard to follow the discussion ;)

Comment: done, updated to show log in button too `<tr><td><input type=submit value="Log In">`

Comment: ok this seems to have done it:
`#username field
$usernameField = $doc.getElementsByName("desc")
($usernameField |select -first 1).value = "xxxxx"
        
#password field
$passwordField = $doc.getElementsByName("password")
($passwordField |select -first 1).value = "xxxxx"` but I can't get the button to click now *grrrrrrrrr*

Comment: had to use form name to get it to submit, working now:
`<form name=main method=POST`
`$ie2.document.getElementById("main").submit()`

Answer (score 0):

used the input form name in order to press the button, all the code needed to get it working was:

```
#username field
$usernameField = $doc.getElementsByName("desc")
($usernameField |select -first 1).value = "xxxxx"

#password field
$passwordField = $doc.getElementsByName("password")
($passwordField |select -first 1).value = "xxxxx"

$ie2.document.getElementById("main").submit()
```